# HUMHUB: How can i give specific users file permission?

Tags: file, permissions, file-permissions, social-networking, social-network-friendship

**Three Questions**

**1. Example Groups:**

1. Admins (#All Files)
2. Colleagues (#File1, File2)
3. Partners (#File3)

*// Info: # <- for Permission.*

**2. And whats the difference between:**

> Username->Administration->Users->Tab("Groups")

*and*

> Dashboard->Members->Tab("Members")

?

*// 3. Info: Tag "Humhub" dont exist, what to do?*

Comment: As current solution: 1. Making 3 new spaces with explicit file uploads hence file permission management not included yet github.com/humhub/humhub-modules-cfiles/issues/19 and https://github.com/humhub/humhub-modules-cfiles/issues/14 2. Groups are for just for permission to make new spaces. 3. I need 1500 reputations to make a new tag so a other one can make a "humhub"-tag please!

Comment: im now about to install humhub on my own linux server to experiment with the code ^^